# Excel: Many Rows - Colum Data to Rows

Tags: excel

I have the following table with information in it.

```
1. A B C
2. D E
3. F G H I J K L M 
4. N O P 
5. Q
6. R S T U V W X Y Z
```

.

What I am after is the following:

```
A
B
C
..
X
Y 
Z
```

Thoughts / Suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Edit: I have tried the =TRANSPOSE FUCTION and that doesn't work :'(

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Pick some cell outside your table area and enter:

<strike>=IF(OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/9,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,9))="","",OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/9,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,9)))</strike>

then copy downward:

[image]

As you see, the blanks at the end of each row are preserved.  If you want those blanks removed, that is easy.

**EDIT#1:**

The original formula has an error.  The correct formula should be:

```
=IF(OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/9,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,9))=0,"",OFFSET($A$1,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/9,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,9)))
```

Comment: Nice. I had just worked out a similar solution involving `INDEX()` with modular arithmetic, but my first approach yielded `0` rather than blanks, I had a complicated idea of first replacing all blanks in the original range by a place marker (like `"#"`), using my formula, and then using `GOTO` to select and then delete the place markers (after converting to values). Your solution avoids that complexity.

Comment: @JohnColeman  Sadly John the formula seems to have a problem beginning in row **4**, it is displaying **0** rather than the blank.

Comment: Maybe you have to use the kludge that I was forced to use. It is weird that in your case the problem showed up in the 4th row instead of right away.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I try to avoid VBA (as per Gary's Student's answer) but in this case the VBA is easier to understand so I might make an exception:

```
Public Function Vectorize(data As Range) As Variant
    Dim Result() As Variant
    ReDim Result(1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(data))
    Dim r, c, n As Long
    n = 0
    For r = 1 To data.Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To data.Columns.Count
            If Not (IsEmpty(data(r, c))) Then
                n = n + 1
                Result(n) = data(r, c)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    Vectorize = Application.Transpose(Result)
End Function
```

This function also ignores blank cells.

The result is returned as a column array; to use, select the cells you want the output in, type the formula `=Vectorize(A1:I6)` (assuming your data is in `A1:I6`) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to evaluate it as an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this perhaps more flexibly by repeated application of offset/subtotal. Starting in (say) K2

```
=IFERROR(IF(ROWS($1:1)<=COUNTA(A$1:I$1),INDEX(A$1:I$1,ROWS($1:1)),
INDEX(A$1:I$10,MATCH(TRUE,SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A$1,0,0,ROW(A$1:I$10),10))>=ROWS($1:1),0),
ROWS($1:1)-SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A$1,0,0,MATCH(TRUE,SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A$1,0,0,ROW(A$1:I$10),10))>=ROWS($1:1),0)-1,ROWS(A$1:I$10))))),"")
```

Must be entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]